# pyspark persist changes to variable outside of mapper scope

Tags: python, scope, pyspark

In python, I can do this for example:

```
lRet = []
llData = [range(3) for i in range(5)]
def func(l):
    lRet.append(l[0])
    return l

map(func, llData)
print(lRet)

-> [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Now, I want to do something similar in `PySpark`.  My reason is that I need to create something external to my RDD from data that is in my rdd.  Lets do the same:

```
lRet = []
#rddData.collect() is of form llData above
def func(l):
    lRet.append(l[0])
    return l

rddData.map(func).collect()
print lRet

-> []
```

I have also just noticed that doing the first example in a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` on a local pyspark instance gives the same result of `lRet` being unchanged, even though it keeps track of `lRet` internally.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you create `lRet`, are you only adding/appending to it? Does order matter as you add / append?

Comment: @KatyaHandler Well, in real life I want to read/write to a sparse matrix.  I figured the concept should be the same, so I created much simpler example code.  To your question: I'm using indeces to access said matrix (analogy coming from llData), so order does not matter

Comment: So, the problem with doing this in parallel is that what happens if two different tasks need to make a change (that isn't additive) at location (x,y) in your sparse matrix? Maybe node 1 thinks matrix(x,y) = 1 while node 7 thinks matrix(x,y) = 0. Which is right? This can't be done in parallel, because there is inherently ordering. Only way is for additive properties, which can be done using [accumulators](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators).

Comment: @KatyaHandler I can work with only additive matrix access.  I'll look at accumulators.  Thanks

Comment: @KatyaHandler Would you please take a look at this question I created about how to actually create and use the accumulator?  I think I'm mostly there, just missing a small element.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36196648/pyspark-sparse-matrix-accumilator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is it is not possible. Spark programming doesn't cover the tools required to maintain shared mutable state. When you execute your code each executor interpreter get its own copy of the `lRet` variable which is modified locally and discarded later.

As mentioned by [Katya Handler in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36182747/pyspark-persist-changes-to-variable-outside-of-mapper-scope#comment60004441_36182747) Spark provides `accumulators` but these are write-only, doesn't guarantee consistent results when used outside actions, and the driver state is update per task using `fold` like logic.

There are projects which use long running tasks and external synchronization primitives on top of Spark but it is a completely different model.