# pyspark matrix accumulator

Tags: python, sparse-matrix, pyspark

I want to additively populate a matrix with values inferred from an `rdd` using a [pyspark accumulator](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators); I found the docs a bit unclear.  Adding a bit of background, just in case its relevant.
My `rddData` contains lists of indexes for which one count has to be added to the matrix.  For example this list maps to indices:
`[1,3,4] -> (11), (13), (14), (33), (34), (44)`

Now, here is my accumulator:

```
from pyspark.accumulators import AccumulatorParam
class MatrixAccumulatorParam(AccumulatorParam):
    def zero(self, mInitial):
        import numpy as np
        aaZeros = np.zeros(mInitial.shape)
        return aaZeros

    def addInPlace(self, mAdd, lIndex):
        mAdd[lIndex[0], lIndex[1]] += 1
        return mAdd
```

So this is my mapper function:

```
def populate_sparse(lIndices):
    for i1 in lIndices:
        for i2 in lIndices:
            oAccumilatorMatrix.add([i1, i2])
```

And then run the data:

```
oAccumilatorMatrix = oSc.accumulator(aaZeros, MatrixAccumulatorParam())

rddData.map(populate_sparse).collect()
```

Now, when I look at my data:

```
sum(sum(oAccumilatorMatrix.value))
#= 0.0
```

Which it shouldn't be.  What am I missing?

**EDIT**
Tried this with a sparse matrix at first, got this traceback that sparse matrices are not supported.  Changed question for dense numpy matrix:

```
...

    raise IndexError("Indexing with sparse matrices is not supported"
IndexError: Indexing with sparse matrices is not supported except boolean indexing where matrix and index are equal shapes.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aha!  I think I got it.  The accumulator, at the end of the day, still needs to add its own pieces to itself.  So, change `addInPlace` to:

```
def addInPlace(self, mAdd, lIndex):
    if type(lIndex) == list:
        mAdd[lIndex[0], lIndex[1]] += 1
    else:
        mAdd += lIndex
    return mAdd
```

So now it adds indices when it is given a list, and adds itself after the `populate_sparse` function loop to create my final matrix.

Comment: You are a genius. Been banging my head against this for couple hours!!